# How to set `ListView` height automatically depending on the number of items in `Xamarin Forms`?

Tags: listview, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am `ListView` to display items on my screen. The items I display varies in count. So my question is: how can I set the height of my `ListView` automatically depending on the number of items? Right now I have my `ListView` occupying my screen all the way to the bottom like the picture below.

[image]

I want it to look like the image below (which uses a `TableView`):

[image]

PS: I am working on a PCL application but open to create renderers. At the moment I'm just working on the PCL and iOS side, so iOS renderers is much appreciated.

**Edits: Additional XAML code:**

```
<ListView x:Name="categoryGroupListView" ItemTapped="openCategoriesPage" HasUnevenRows="true">
    <ListView.Header>
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            // Header code here
        </StackLayout>
    </ListView.Header>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <ListView.DataTemplate>
            <TextCell Text="{Binding CategoryName}" Detail="{Binding Count}"/>
        </ListView.DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your row of variable height as per item inside your row then you have to use property (HasunevenRows="true") inside listview.
Example-

```
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate >
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell>
                                    <ViewCell.View>
                                       //..............                                                
                                    </ViewCell.View>
                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check out Xamarin's [Evolve app sample](https://github.com/xamarinhq/app-evolve) for this. It has some `ListViews` in there that mimic `TableView` look and feel. It uses custom classes for it such as a `NonScrollableListView` and a `CardView`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the default in iOS. You can remove the extra cells in the ListView (UITableView) using a custom renderer and adding an empty view to the footer.

something like:

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ListView> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);

    if (this.Control == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    this.Control.TableFooterView = new UIView();
}
```

This is also possible using the footer property directly on the ListView in the XAML

```
<ListView.Footer>
    <Label />
</ListView.Footer>
```

Either option will remove the empty cells.

Hope this helps.-